# Analyze files and documents contents and suggest folder structure and clustering

Tags: windows, data-visualization, data-analysis, document-indexing, clustering

I need a Windows software that:

1. analyzes my files (docs, spreadsheets, images, PDF, presentations, etc.) and their contents
2. suggests a folder structure and clustering for managing and storing files

And ideally index files and contents for better searching and visualize data structure and relations.

Should I use data mining or business intelligence tools?